# Vue 3 is it good to use reactive on static objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vuejs3

I have a variable *rules* that holds an object for validating a form. From reading some blogs and watching tutorials I've learned that ref is for primitive values and reactive is for objects/arrays.

So my question is do I need to use reactive when an object is just static?

What's the best practice?

```
const rules = reactive({
      name: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Name is required"
          trigger: "blur"
        }
      ],
      age: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Age is required",
          trigger: "blur"
        }
      ],
      email: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Email is required",
          trigger: "blur"
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: It's a constant, right ? you do not need either a ref or a reactive. Just use the object directly.

Comment: Yeah it's a constant. What is the downside of using reactive when an object is constant?

Comment: It is clear that you don't understand what `reactive` does. I humbly suggest that you find out (from the official Vue.js documentation, hopefully) instead of seeking more pre-thought answers from random people.

Comment: @PenAndPapers Not related to this question: I have created an answer regarding the question you asked a few minutes ago, which got deleted. I think it was a good question so I answered it. View the working answer on https://jsfiddle.net/9naj6mcu/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)

> In computing, reactive programming is a declarative programming paradigm concerned with data streams and the propagation of change.

In essence theres no benefit from having a reactive property if you don't need to track its changes. In your case it looks like what you have is a constant and not a property that needs to be tracked when its changed or not.

Rule of thumb:

*Do I need to track changes to this variable?*

- if yes, then it probably should be reactive
- if no, then just store it in an immutable variable (using `const` for example)

You can also combine `Object.freeze` here if you would like to prevent other people from modifying such objects:

```
const rules = Object.freeze({
      name: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Name is required"
          trigger: "blur"
        }
      ],
      age: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Age is required",
          trigger: "blur"
        }
      ],
      email: [
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Email is required",
          trigger: "blur"
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: `const` does not make the object immutable it makes the variable immutable.

Comment: Besides that with `reactive(…)` you track changes to the properties of the object returned by `reactive`. That returned object can for sure be stored in a `const` variable as well. `const rules = reactive( … )` is perfectly valid and normally what you want.